# How can I help an unfriendly dog with a serious wound?

Tags: dogs, injury

I feel like seeing coils of intestine through the cut wound or it may be the muscle I'm not sure. A staff here said its infested with maggots. The dog is kinda irritated one , doesn't allow any one to go near  . we are unable to restrain him. So i can't find out whether its infested with maggots. I see no signs of pus or blood. Since it is in breast area he has the access to lick it. But for precaution can i spray med. turpentine oil ? Will it cause harm if maggots aren't there? Would oral ivernectin heal that ? Or any other antibiotic course should be given?

Comment: You don't say where you are or what resources you have. Can you feed the dog some meat with a tranquilizer in it? Do you have a slip lead you could thread through a pvc pipe to make a catch pole? Honestly, if you are seeing intestines and the wound is old enough for maggots, you are probably not going to be able to save the dog, so if you can put it down humanely that is probably kindest.

Comment: As a start give the dog some food and fresh water

Answer (score 1):

Please find a way to get this dog seen by a veterinarian. Even if you can't restrain the dog, perhaps you can get a veterinarian to visit your location and determine if the dog has maggots or intestines poking through the wound (both conditions are serious).

I do not recommend the use of turpentine oil on such a potentially serious wound, turpentine oil can harm the body's ability to heal.

Comment: I think Zaralynda has it. I'd also suggest calling animal control. The vet probably isn't going to come out and try to catch a dog. Even if they do, they'll charge you. Animal control handles things like this for a living. They'll come catch the dog for free and make sure it gets treated. They'll also handle finding out if it has an owner and if it does, why it was left in this condition without medical treatment. They'll take appropriate legal action if necessary, against the owners. Also, if it doesn't have an owner, they can try to get it adopted. It'll get good treatment either way.